# Visual Studio Code debug doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

When I attempt to debug my project, the debugger is not stopping at the breakpoints.  I have a solution with 3 projects. I have done the following:

I have gone over links to many solutions for this issue, including those on stackoverflow, but none of them have resolved the problem.

```
+Confirmed that the breakpoints are active
+Clean solution
+Rebuild solution
+confirm configuration on project is set to Debug
+Deleted the bin folder for the project, then IISreset and then build
```

No error messages.

Here is sample code - the breakpoint was set but not hit on the line: Session["default"] = "default";.   This is in the page load event.  No matter where I set a breakpoint, the breakpoints are ignored.  I am in DEBUG and not RELEASE.

This project has been working fine for years until yesterday.

```
namespace Pollinators
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            ViewStateUserKey = User.Identity.Name;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["default"] = "default";
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.RedirectPermanent("http://wisconsinpollinators.com/SubmitFrom_Nwsltr.aspx");
        }

        protected void btnMasonBees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.RedirectPermanent("http://wisconsinpollinators.com/Bees/MasonBee.aspx");
        }

        protected void btnVolunteerNaturalist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.RedirectPermanent("http://xerces.org/xerces-bee-monitoring-tools/");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're working with? It's difficult to solve a problem with no frame of reference. Alternatively, set the breakpoints higher in the chain. Establish a baseline where you know for sure that the application will hit the breakpoint, and then `F10` your way down the line. My guess is there is either some code that closes execution before your breakpoint, or possibly an unhandled exception that isn't caught before your breakpoint so it skips it.

Comment: Are you connecting to the Debug executable or the Release Executable?  Should be using the Debug Executable.

Comment: Possible issue in debug mode may be enabled optimization.

Comment: How do you start or attach the debugger?

Comment: I attach to the debugger either using F5 or Debug>Start Debugging

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have experienced this unusual behaviour in Visual Studio in Debug mode. What I have noticed is that Visual studio gets hanged whilst loading symbols.

You can see if that is the case for you - by checking the status bar at the very bottom of Visual Studio UI.

I have seen this behaviour when debugging using F5 and Chrome as browser. Switching to a different browser such as FireFox - if the above applies - does fix the issue.

You can also try attaching to IIS - I do use this tool [Attach To All The Things](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thebread.AttachToAllTheThings) 
Simpy run your local host and from the Tools menu' in Visual studio, use `Attach to IIS`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks . I did download the 'Attach to all the things' but I need clarification on what to do in the Tools menu to attach to IIS … I don't see a menu option.

Comment: ops just added a picture for the next generation :-)

Comment: No, it's still not working right.  I was able to hit a breakpoint on my default page but no other breakpoints are working on other pages.  Also, I'm not seeing all those menu options on my Tools menu.  From your list, Connect to Database is the first option I see.  I'm using VS 2019

Comment: I am also using VS2019, the process I usually follow is rebuild, lunch localhost, attach to IIS, refresh, breakpoint hit.